# Which variant of French is spoken in La Répétition?

Tags: accents-régionaux, dialectes

I'm trying to figure out whether the people in the movie [*La Répétition*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_R%C3%A9p%C3%A9tition_%28film,_2001%29) are speaking Canadian or France's French, specifically in the [opening scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRdBGVuSUTA). The movie has a Canadian and a French actress.

Comment: The people are speaking French from France in this video.

Comment: Thanks.  :-)  How can you tell? Is it sentence structure?

Comment: @verve It's the pronunciation that will give away Canadian French right away. First of all, they pronounce nasal sounds differently in Canada.

Answer (score 3):

**It is French from France.**

Here are some indications that I picked up on:

- 0:16 "Je suis là, Louise"

  - This sentence, which means "I am here, Louise" is more often used in France than it is in Canada.  In the Acadian variety of French you are more likely to hear "Je suis ici" which will sound like 'ih-SIT'.  It is also not uncommon to hear "Je suis ici" (with the standard pronunciation) in Quebec.
- Multiple points: Pronunciation of 'tu'.  In France you hear a clear 'tu'.  In Quebec, one would hear a slight variation which leads to a very slight 'tzu' or 'tchu' sound.  This is very difficult to explain using text though.  It is very, very subtle.
- Nasal sounds and enunciation.  Parisian French tends to be spoken more fluidly with the mouth slightly more closed than Quebec French.  Quebec French is less fluid, has more emphasized consonant sounds, and a difference in nasal tone partly due to this difference in enunciation.

Comment: "More anglicisms are used in Quebec French" is absolutely false.  And if you don't believe me, it's even stated in the wiki you linked: **In contrast, Quebecers show a stronger aversion to the use of anglicisms in formal contexts than do European francophones, largely because of what the influence of English on their language is held to reveal about the historically superior position of anglophones in Canadian society.**

Comment: And even on the streets you'll ear less english words than in Europe.  "Fin de semaine" rather than "Weekend", "magasinage" rather than "shopping", etc.

Comment: @Phil You are absolutely right.  Such 'mail' vs 'courriel'.  I must have been thinking of the Shiac variety when I wrote that.  I will edit.

Comment: [What about less formal contexts?](http://www.zviane.com/prout/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/C0008.jpg) (by Zviane — can’t find the post, this is directly image).

Comment: When French is taught in highschool in Canada which pronunciation do they teach?  Canadian or France?

Comment: @Édouard depends on where you live and with who you talk. But where am I (Quebec), it's really not as terrible as depicted by the comic you linked.

Comment: @verve we have multiple "Canadian french pronounciation subsets", only in Quebec (province), let alone New-Brunswick...  Different pronounciations I know: Quebec, Montreal, Beauce, Cote-Nord, Saguenay, Gaspesie, etc.  I don't think other provinces learn french that much.

Comment: @verve In the French Immersion system for school and even when studying French in university, as I am, a lot of it will depend on your instructor or teacher.  Standard French (as maintained by L'Académie française) is the main goal but you will always get a slight pronunciation variation which will come from the teacher (whether they be anglophone, Quebecois, Acadian, French, or even from parts of Africa).  I have an instructor or teacher of each type and they try not let their native tendencies influence the teaching, but it usually does to some point anyways.

Comment: @verve Many French immersion students (anglophones learning French in public school) in Eastern Canada tend to develop something I call the 'French Immersion Student Accent'. This accent is heavily anglophone - French words are pronounced correctly but the sentences flow like English. This is mainly due to peer pressures from other students in elementary and high school. For some reason, an effort to imitate a Parisian French accent is something that many students would be teased for.  In university, I have found that this dissipates and students begin to imitate a French accent.

Comment: @verve My intermediate French instructor in University was from Cameroon.  He was strict about proper pronunciation regarding mistakes that anglophones usually make.  An example of this would be the word 'voisin', where there is an 's' between two vowels, thus leading to a 'z' sound rather that an 's' sound.  Even though he was strict about this, he had tendencies that deviated from standard French.  For example, his pronunciation of verbs like 'rire', 'lire', or 'grandir' would always drop the 'r' at the end and instead be pronounced like 'rit', 'lit', and 'grandis'.  So it depends, you see!

Comment: @Édouard Sometimes in humorous contexts (like comics or television) in Canada, more Anglicisms and slang are thrown in to add to the humor - sometimes this can even be the subject of the humour.  [Check this out](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=07URgCvODVs) and you may understand what I mean.

Comment: @Patrick: Very informative!  Merci.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound Canadian to me, they're from France I believe.

Answer (score 0):

That's totally french from France, no doubt. It's all about the pronunciation, which is well detailed in another response.
Beside that, Emmanuel Béart (the actress on the bike with a red pullover) is from France, as the whole film (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0253612/).

Comment: You may consider making your answer more complete.  Explain why it is from France.